# How to assign new value to an element in an array (MATLAB)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

How do I use `max` function to set the value of the highest element in a vector to 1? For example, let `A` be a matrix of size 3 rows and 2 columns. I want to set `A(:,1) = [0.9 0.03 0.01]'` to B(:,1) = `[1 0 0]`. Repeating the same for the second column of A. So, I should get `B = [1 0 0; 0 1 0]`. So, I could obtain the index of the maximum element in each column. I don't know how to assign and change the value.This is what I could do. Please help.

```
A =

    0.9000    0.1000
    0.0300    0.5800
    0.0100    0.0020

>> [ans,ind] = max(A)

ans =

    0.9000    0.5800


ind =

     1     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` returns the index within each column. Thus the subscripts you want to set are given by `i = ind` and `j = 1:size(A,2)`, the second just indexes each column. Unfortunately, `B(i,j)` does not do what you want in this case, it indexes each combination of `i` and `j`.

`sub2ind` converts subscripts to linear indices:

```
lin = sub2ind(size(A), ind, 1:size(A,2))
```

should return the vector `[1,5]`. Linear indices run along columns. `B(lin)` does exactly what you need:

```
B = zeros(size(A));
B(lin) = 1;
```

---

At the expense of a bit more computation, you can simplify the above a lot.
For newer versions of MATLAB, that do implicit singleton expansion, you can  do:

```
B = A == max(A);
```

Here we just find, for each column, the element that matches the maximum for that column, and set it to `true` (which has a value of 1). If your version of MATLAB does not support implicit singleton expansion, you can use `bsxfun` to accomplish the same things:

```
B = bsxfun(@eq, A, max(A));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first option works but the second option `B=A==max(A)` throws error which is `Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.` I have MATLAB 2011Rb version. Is it something to do with this version of MATLAB that I get this error?

Comment: @SrishtiM: Yes, as I mentioned, that syntax only works for newer versions of MATLAB. In this case "newer" means from the last two or three years. Try the `bsxfun` option, it will work with your version of MATLAB.